# pip freeze > requirements.txt - permission denied with sudo? (heroku- flask tutorial)

Tags: python, linux, heroku, flask, sudo

I am attempting to run this command during the heroku-flask tutorial

```
sudo pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

I still receive the below message

```
bash: requirements.txt: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 9):

looks like you don't have write permission in the folder your working in. This should solve the issue.

```
sudo sh -c 'sudo pip freeze > requirements.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing `pip` with `sudo`, you may want `sudo`'s `-H` flag.

Try using

```
sudo -H sh -c 'sudo pip freeze > requirements.txt'
```